# Cannot redrag a dropped element on a droppable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to create a page where I want to drag a button on a place.
I want to drag it again if I want to change the position of button.
But its not working out.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="extern1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/external/jquery.js>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="drag" class="btn btn-primary">Drag me</button>
<div id="drop">Drop here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app1.js page code

```
$(function () {
$('#drag').draggable({
    cursor : "move",
    helper : function (event) {
        return $('<div class="col-xs-2"><button class="btn btn-primary check">
Button</button></div>');
    },
    //appendTo : "#drop",
    cancel : false
});
$("#drop").droppable({
    drop : function (event, ui) {
        //clone and remove positioning from the helper element
        var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
            .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
            .css({
                position : 'absolute'
            });
        $(this).append(newDiv);
    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the cloned element as `draggable()` as well, as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#drag').draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: function(event) {
      return $('<div class="col-xs-2"><button class="btn btn-primary check">Button</button></div>');
    },
    cancel: false
  });
  $("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      //clone and remove positioning from the helper element
      var $newDiv = ui.helper.clone(false)
        .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
        .css({
          position: 'absolute'
        }).draggable({ //make it draggable
          cancel: false
        }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="drag" class="btn btn-primary">Drag me</button>
<div id="drop">Drop here</div>
```

Comment: But its creating a duplicate element on dragging it for the second time.

Comment: @AshishSantikari This is according to your logic. You are creating a new element on `drop`. Your issue was *"Cannot redrag a dropped element"*. I fixed that issue. Now if you just `drag` new element  it'll not create dup element. If you `drop` the item inside droppable then it'll create new draggable because that's what you've written.

Comment: @AshishSantikari BTW - re-read your question. The answer answers what is being asked. You ask something, you get the answer... We can't read your mind... So maybe update the question with a clear problem statement. Explain what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: Ok. Then can you help me with the solution for my "supposed to be" question??

Comment: @AshishSantikari Sure, I only told so, so that you can ask improve your questions in in future.

Comment: @AshishSantikari So let me assume what you want - You want to drag the draggable item `#drag`, make a copy of it once you drop it in droppable `#drop`. When you drag or drop the *copy* draggables, it should not be cloned no matter what. In other words you can only clone elements by dragging `#drag` and dropping in `#drop`. Am I correct..?

Comment: yes. I want to drag the #drag element onto the .drop area and I want to reposition it in the .drop area . I do not want duplicate elements getting created.